# Is there a way to identify the user who owns a process from /proc/PID

Tags: linux

I am parsing process details from `/proc/PID` and I am so far unable to find out who owns a process from that meta directory's files.

[Documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) does not seem to point to that info as well.

Comment: If you just want to see the process' owner (without parsing `/proc`), [these answers](https://superuser.com/questions/479746/how-to-find-pids-user-name-in-linux/1024197) might help. For example: `ps -u -p 1234`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The owner of the process is the owner of all files in the `/proc/PID` directory.

```
$ ls -l /proc/27595
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x   2 me users 0 Jul 14 11:53 attr
-r--------   1 me users 0 Jul 14 11:53 auxv
...
```

Also the file `/proc/PID/loginuid` holds the UID of the owner of the process.

```
$ cat /proc/27595/loginuid
1000
```

Answer (score 4):

The owner of the files *in* /proc/[pid]/ is not always the user -- programs can e.g. make themselves "non-dumpable" to avoid leaking sensitive information if they become another user, and then the file ownership of the files *in* the directory can change to root.

But normally the UID of the process can be retrieved by an fstat call (or a stat command ) on the /proc/[pid] *directory* itself.

Comment: "But normally the UID of the process can be retrieved by an fstat call (or a stat command ) on the /proc/[pid] directory itself.". Could you please also add an authoritative link/reference to this part?

Answer (score 2):

The user and group IDs (real, effective, saved set, and filesystem) are listed in `/proc/<PID>/status>`, in the row which begins with `Uid:`. Looking at the ownership of `/proc/<PID>` is unreliable for the reasons listed in the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), namely the owner depends on the value of the process's "dumpable" attribute.