# How to kill all processes of a particular user in Linux using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I want to kill all processes of a particular user in Linux using C#.I know all the running process in my system,but unable to find the user attached to each process.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366362/is-there-a-way-to-identify-the-user-who-owns-a-process-from-proc-pid) answer your question?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just _log them out?_.  _[How do I kill all a user's processes using their UID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/how-do-i-kill-all-a-users-processes-using-their-uid)_.  Just have c# shell out to perform the steps